# PHP looping thrue milti array with foreach

Tags: php, foreach

i need to loop thru array with foreach and only list cars that are  younger then 2000

```
$cars = array(array("model"=>"Volvo","year"=>2010),array("model"=>"BMW","year"=>1995),array("model"=>"Saab","year"=>1998),array("model"=>"Land Rover","year"=>2004)
```

Comment: Refer to the PHP documentation for [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and have a pleasant day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$cars = array(
    array(
        "model" => "Volvo",
        "year" => 2010
    ) ,
    array(
        "model" => "BMW",
        "year" => 1995
    ) ,
    array(
        "model" => "Saab",
        "year" => 1998
    ) ,
    array(
        "model" => "Land Rover",
        "year" => 2004
    )
);


foreach($cars as $car){
    if($car['year'] > 2000){

//Write code to do what you want to do with the car. Next line just prints it.

        echo $car['model'].'</br>' ;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Volvo
Land Rover
```

Foreach loop takes each of the car in $car variable which is another array. inside foreach check for the value in model. if is younger than 2000 then do whatever you want to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$cars = array(array("model"=>"Volvo","year"=>2010),array("model"=>"BMW","year"=>1995),array("model"=>"Saab","year"=>1998),array("model"=>"Land Rover","year"=>2004) );

$size = sizeof( $cars );

echo "You have $size cars in the array\n";

$i=0;
foreach( $cars as $car )
{
    if( $car['year'] < 2000 )
    {
            echo $car['model'] .' - '.$car['year']."\n";
    }
}
```